# What organization could take over monster hunting, which was the job of a single organization that's completely gone now?

Tags: science-based, medieval, military

Now, there are monsters in this world, not exactly the most original though. You have your vampires, werewolves, zombies, wights, etc...

Monsters were always at odds with humanity, especially the Church. While monsters were physically stronger and faster, mankind had the numbers and the Church, and the Church had <s>the Belmonts</s> a family of nobles who more or less dedicated their existence to eradicating monsters in !Europe (! means NOT. In context, Europe with the serial numbers filed off), and they were legendary at it, though no one else hunted monsters, so there's that.

One day, however, Mephistopheles (the demon lawyer, not me) decided to end this family. His invention, the MK.1 Cyber Armor proved to be sufficient, and though he killed not just the men, but the women and the children too, the Cyber Armor was destroyed as well.

Now, the SNAFU level of mankind's situation is lowered by several factors:

First, many monsters were just trying to live a quiet life and actively avoided humanity and continue to do so even now. Werewolves always avoided humans, there are many vampires that live in hiding and try not to participate in vampire society. Even among those vampires that do have armies and power, some are busy inventing better topical anesthetics, so their *"Bleed for Alucard"* blood donation campaign would gain traction, and see little use for war anyway. Zombies are just meat robots under the vampires' control.

Second is that the nanites that dwell on silver surfaces are highly poisonous to monsters and demons (they can't penetrate armor, though). The noble family and their knowledge were blown up with the rest of their castle, but this one thing is widely known.

Still, there's the werewolf equivalent of the provisional IRA who go after influential people and attempt to infect them and thus turn human society against itself until it collapses. Then, there are the conspiring vampires, the Viking vampires, and the serial-killing vampires like Jack, the DVD-ripper.

So the war still rages within, and peaceful monsters still can't hope to negotiate with humanity, as it remained dead-set on total genocide.

To be able to continue that, humans would obviously try to fill the crater that the <s>Belmonts</s> left and there must have been some roadblocks (check and balance) in place so that the family would remain the Church's Black Ops and nothing more.

**Yet, I'm still struggling. Just what pre-existing medieval organization(s) would have the manpower, infrastructure, and size to be a suitable replacement goldfish? Especially since werewolves can convert the living, and vampires can make the dead into zombie grunts.**

Tech-level is late-medieval. Humans only know that silver is poisonous to monsters, but are unaware of the nanites. Some vampires are more advanced and even have electricity, but they stay hidden enough for that to be irrelevant. Demons have advanced tech but can't interfere anymore. The DVD-ripper was a joke name by me.

Since just about every second fantasy does this, the setting is the rough outlines (so no specific people or dates, please) of late-medieval Europe, that's where the monsters are, anything beyond it is irrelevant.

Comment: "The" Church existed basically only in Europe during the Middle Ages, and not even in all of Europe; for example, most of the Iberian Peninsula was Muslim during most of the Middle Ages. What would be the relationship between "the" Church and a family operating in not Europe? (And you definitely need to specify a place; in the Middle Ages the world was fragmented into several sub-worlds which simply did not interact all that much, as in between not at all and very very little. Unless you pick one of those sub-worlds one cannot possibly tell what organization could etc. etc.)

Comment: I cannot shake the feeling that you wrote story to Assasin creed but replaced assasins with "church", Illuminati with vampires/werewolfes and cohortes, and "lineage" with "Belmontes".

Comment: Really enjoy your questions.

Comment: Knight order ? sounds like crusader material there, or spanish inquisition (nobody expect them).  or just goes bounty hunter like witcher do, it work for australia after their defeat in great emu war.

Comment: If the Belmonts where church black ops, wouldn't the church enlist more black ops? or just go legit and have some holy knight crusades? I fail to see where the church might just ignore the loss of a pawn, Oops, "Holy Order".

Answer (score 1):

By the Lord, the Knights of the Temple will discharge the sacred duty as they always had.

We forswear spouses,
we relinquish our mundane fortunes,
we train for the fight.

!Belmonts were favoured by the Church, yet the wheel turned, and their guarded secrets perished with them.
It is upon us, brothers and sisters of the faith, to carry on the Good Fight.

I, Jean Jaques Robierre Cheval d' BirthTown, Grand Maestre of this Holy Order, do commission the creation of a select group. They will fight where Angels fear to tread.

Answer (score 1):

**Different monsters come to help!**

The third season, and plot threads from season 1 were wrapped up definitively in season 2.   But your show got renewed!  How to inject new energy?

New monsters!  For your scenario, I propose underworlders: fair folk because they are sweet eye candy with glowy magic and people will click on your trailer to see what those good looking and superbly well dressed folks are up to.  Plus the fair folk are an unknown and chaotic quantity.  Are they allies of humans?  Is that one in the violet seeing someone?   Why do they want to help humans fight monsters?  Are they actually helping humans fight monsters?  Do you think that one in the violet would like Thai food?  Because there is a great place I know.

Yes yes; elf fair folk supermodels from the underworld will come help fight monsters with glowy magic, kung fu and under worldly weapons.  People will mostly not be suspicious of them because every single one is smoking hot.   There may be something else going on.  Maybe that one in the violet with the violet eyes will confess the elf plan after being plied with pad thai and falling in love with me.

Comment: Take my upvote and go wash your hands, you dirty writer you!

Comment: Uhmmm. But if I introduce thots into the world, then the thot slayers will pop up as a balance. Not only that, but the Meanwhiles, the Neverweres, the BRBs, and the Carpet Furry will come through as well and they'll drag the world into the depths of Heck.